# jQuery swap video sources then .load() not working in IE8 /Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, video, internet-explorer-8

I have a video gallery which requires me to be able to swap out the href's of the mp4 and the alternative ogv video files with a single click, and then load the new source to the page.

The script I wrote works perfectly in Firefox but not in IE or in Chrome.

I've checked the variable are populating and I've tried setting the cache to false and appending the urls with random strings but still no joy.

Here's the script:

```
//Click and Hover events for thumbnail list
$(".video_thumb ul li:first").addClass('active'); 

$(".video_thumb ul li").click(function(){ 
    //Set Variables
    var vidAlt = $(this).find('img').attr("alt"); //Get Alt Tag of Image
    var vidSrc = $(this).find('a').attr("href"); //Get video link href
    var vidAltSrc = vidSrc.replace(".mp4", ".ogv"); //Create 2nd variable with alternate source

    if ($(this).is(".active")) {  //If it's already active, then...
        return false; // Don't click through
    } else {
        //Swap out video links  
    $('#vid video source#video1').attr('src', vidSrc);
        $('#vid video source#video2').attr('src', vidAltSrc);
        $('#vid video').attr('title', vidAlt);
        $('#vid video').load(); 

    };

    $(".video_thumb ul li").removeClass('active'); //Remove class of 'active' on all lists
    $(this).addClass('active');  //add class of 'active' on this list only
    return false;

}) .hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

And here's the html for the page:

```
<div class="main_image">
  <div id="vid">
    <video width="600" controls title="Video Title" style="z-index:1000;">
                <source id="video1" src="videos/video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
                <source id="video2" src="videos/video.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
            </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should use $(".video_thumb ul li").each(function(){$(this).click(function(){ ....
in place of 
$(".video_thumb ul li").click(function(){

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code - I've tried it and unfortunately it's still not working in Chrome/IE. You can see the live code at http://www.serpentarmy.co.uk/video_gallery_1.html and the script at http://www.serpentarmy.co.uk/scripts/master.js (video gallery section). The variables seem to be populating ok, it's just not loading properly. Thanks again.